# any annotations for a field which is like db generated sequence in JAVA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a scenario where there is a DB column which should be like sequence for each primary key + another column. The column's value should again reset and start from 1 for another.

For example:

col1(PK)------col2(FK)-------my-column

0---------------0-------------------1

1---------------0-------------------2

2---------------0-------------------3

3---------------1-------------------1

4---------------1-------------------2

5---------------1-------------------3

For col1(PK), I can simply annotate with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

In the same way, I want to generate value for **my-column** as well.

From the code side, This is what it looks like:

```
classA{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String col2;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "classa", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ClassB> listB = new ArrayList<>();

    //I want to generate/increment the value of myCol each time based on value of col1 & col2
    @Column(name = "my-col")
    private Integer myCol;
//getter/setters
}

ClassB{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "col1")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer col1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "col2")
    private ClassA classa;

//getter/setter
}
```

Comment: col1(PK)------col2(FK)-------my-column belong to table `ClassA` or `ClassB`? Your table names is bad practices.

Comment: ClassA. This is not the real time column name. This is just sample which is similar as my real world application. I am not allowed to post real code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add elements in listB of instance of classA, just generate a value for myCol each time and reset:

```
AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger(1);
classa.setListB(classa.getListB.stream.map(b->b.setMyCol(value.getAndIncrement())))
```

Comment: This will just set 1